# Open source software to record all windows user activity

Tags: windows, open-source

Do you know a software that record all the activity that I am doing?

I mean, software I used, documents I used, URL I visited an else.

I am searching for open-source software, so I can continue developing it.

I know about RescueTime it is not open-source, I didn't like it. (I want report by  the minute)

Comment: If you don't find anything else, look for a keylogger. And, while it is fine to record your own activity, best examine the legal implications before recording someone else's activity.

Comment: I want to improve my productivity, so I want to record all what I am doing, and every 5 minutes, to open the log file and explain why  I did that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here:
http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?t=8364

It have all you need it help to your productivity.
It takes screenshot of what are you doing, and you can send it to you by email.

Comment: How did you find it? what was you search query?

Comment: authotkeys logger